# My truck failed emissions because they couldn't find the EGR

Tags: diesel, emissions, silverado, egr

I just took my 2011 GMC Silverado 2500 w/Duramax in for an emissions test in Utah County. They do more than just emissions test. They look to make sure all the elements of the emissions system are in place. The guy couldn't find the EGR unit, so he failed the truck. I had him point out to me where the EGR should be.

He said it should a silver roundish item screwed on top of the unit circled in this picture (actual picture of my truck engine):

[image: Mechanic's location of EGR unit]

I researched what an EGR looks like in an engine, and I came across multiple pictures of a unit that looks like this:

[image: ...]

As you can see, it has the same elements. Can somebody tell me if I'm off my rocker or confirm that I'm correct in that it is the EGR in the picture, and that the emissions tester was wrong?

Edit:
Somebody sent me this [blog post](https://blog.calibratedpower.com/blog/is-the-egr-on-your-lml-2011-2016-duramax-ruining-your-truck) which shows a complete EGR unit (definitely looks like the one I currently have factory installed in my engine):

[image: ...]

Comment: He is an idiot.

Answer (score 2):

The item is circuit is indeed the EGR valve.

Nothing more to add, you can quite happily tell the tester that he is wrong.